# Getting PHP variable in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to use PHP variables in Javascript but I couldn't. After over 2000 lines of writing different JS functions I was fine avoiding that but now I really needed it. I'm a bit lost on all the ways to go about this but nothing really worked. Here is my sequence:

**index.html** file:

```
...
<script src="myfunctions.js" />
....
```

**myfunctions.js** file:

```
....
function test() {
    var x = <?php echo $_conf['user_id'];?>
    console.log(x);
}
```

I was trying to rename the .js file into .php file and add

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

at the beginning - that didn't work. I was trying to make .htaccess file with

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
```

But that didn't work either. I'm probably missing just a tiny thing. I just need someone fresh and bright to point it out.

Comment: `echo` is not Javascript. At the very least, try `return` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript file should be named as "javascript.php" (just put the name you want, the only important thing is the .php

You have an index.php

Write in your index.php

```
include("javascript.php");
```

Then in your javascript.php

```
<script>
function test(){
     var variable = "<? echo $conf['user_id'] ?>";
     alert(variable);
}
<script>
```

PS: Yo don't need any header.

Comment: This appears to be the only completely correct answer. Changing the file extension(s), and adding `var something=`

Comment: I agree that this one is the correct answer in fact this one only worked. But I have noticed one thing - all the functions in javascript.php file now became visible on the page, i.e. if I save that page on a disk I see all the functions while when it was .js file a user didn't have access to those. Would that be a problem for security?

Comment: The user can always access your javascript code, even in a .js file. It won't be saved in the file if they download it, but they will still know the URL and can download it separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this within your JS code.

```
var php_var = "<?php echo $_conf['user_id'];?>"
```

Comment: Get that extra `echo` out of there, and close the `?>`

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning PHP value to a Javascript variable. Try:

```
var v = "<?php echo $_conf['user_id'];?>";
```

Comment: @NelsonGaldemanGraziano: Thanks, bad copy/paste from question. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing this via a `<script>` tag, your PHP script **MUST** output valid Javascript code, as if you'd literally type your variable assignment in manually. That means doing something like:

HTML/JS:

```
<script src="myscript.php"></script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$myvar = 'foo';
?>

var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myvar); ?>;
```

Which in the end, will produce somethign that will function exactly as if you'd manually typed in the following:

```
<script>
var myvar = 'foo';
</script>
```

Note the use of `json_encode()`. Using this ensures that whatever you're outputting from PHP will become syntactically valid Javascript.

Comment: Why json ? Isn't needed.... you can just use var myvar = '<? echo "whatever"; ?>'; I use it every time...

Comment: it's a safety measure. consider `$name = "Miles O'Brien"` and echoing that into a JS block. Boom. Syntax Error. Kiss your script block goodbye.

Answer (score 0):

#### index.html

```
 ..
<script src="myfunctions.js.php" />
 ...
```

#### myfunctions.js.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
 ...
?>
var val = <?php echo json_encode($val); ?>;
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution is to assign server-side data to attributes in html and read them in javascript. For example index.html could contain something like this:

```
<div id="user-profile" data-user-id="<?php echo $conf['user_id']; ?>"></div>
```

and in js file you can get them while necessary(example with jQuery):

```
var userID = $('#user-profile').attr('data-user-id');
```

Of course you should adjust your server-side settings to process html files.